# Conditionally replacing values in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

Say I have two matrices `A = [ 1 0 0 1 ]` and `B = [ 9 9 7 6 ]`.

If `A(i) != 0` I want to replace `B(i)` with `A(i)`. Is there a built in function in Matlab that can do this? I don't want to use loops.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is as simple as that:

```
B(A ~= 0) = A(A ~= 0)
```

In Matlab **not equal** has the operator `~=` as you could have found out in the [**documentation**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ne.html).
And you should learn some [**basics about matrix indexing**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html), in this case especially **logical indexing**.

Comment: I've answered so many of these kinds of questions that it's hard to find an exact duplicate lol. +1.

Comment: @rayryeng and its faster to answer, than to look for a duplicate ;)